# python, Django related to sendinf pdf using urrlib2

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am working on Django, python and app engine, Can anyone please tell me hoe to send a pdf file to a url using urllib2,(file is InMemoryUploadedFile).  I know there is a question in SOF for sending data using urllib2 with the data being in JSON format..But here I want to send a InMemoryUploadedFile which is a pdf uploaded file from html page. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Python: HTTP Post a large file with streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502596/python-http-post-a-large-file-with-streaming).

You will need to use [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) for streaming the file in memory, then set it to the `request` and set the headers to appropriate mime type i.e `application/pdf` before opening the url.

```
import urllib2
import mmap

# Open the file as a memory mapped string. Looks like a string, but 
# actually accesses the file behind the scenes. 
f = open('somelargefile.pdf','rb')
mmapped_file_as_string = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

# Do the request
request = urllib2.Request(url, mmapped_file_as_string)
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

#close everything
mmapped_file_as_string.close()
f.close()
```

Since Google app engine doesn't have mmap, you might want to write the file in `request.FILES` to the disk temporarily

```
#f is the file from request.FILES
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

And then read the file from there directly using standard file operations.

Another option is to use [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) to write your file to in-memory as a string and then pass it to `urlib2.request`. This can be inefficient in a multi-user environment compared to using a stream.

Comment: It is part of Python standard library optional operating system. Which python version and operating system are you using. Try import mmap at the python interpretor

Comment: It seems like Google app engine doesn't support "mmap" [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608239/using-pygeoip-on-appengine-no-module-named-mmap)

Comment: And one more thing you mentioned in your code as f = open('somelargefile.pdf','rb'),  But in my case the file is comming from Html input(file = request.FILES('file')). Here file is InMemoryUploadedFile, if I write f = open(file,'rb') it throws an error ---> InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'